# Is there a lightweight Windows SDK core?

Tags: python, c++, python-db-api

I  need to compile the C++ source code of a version of Python [DB API for IBM DB2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db):

I am new to this and according to the readme, I need to first download

1. Visual C++ 2003 (isnt it a too old version!?),
2. Platform SDK lastest version (i think its changed to Windows SDK and for I have Win10, i consider to download Windows 10 SDK),
3. .NET SDK Version 1.1

When I tried to download Win10 SDK, I saw that its 2.4GB!! Too heavy and I won't use it for more than these kind of compilations. Is there a lightweight core of it? 
And is this .NET SDK means .NET Framework SDK?

Comment: There can't be a lightweight version because there is no knowing what features of the SDKs you are going to be using. And the SDKs come with Visual Studio, so there is no need to download them separately

Comment: Thank you, thats enlightening for me:)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the windows 10 SDK.  I recommend you use vs2017.  MS's new licensing scheme makes it free for most of us mere mortals. :)

It installs in a bit less time than VS2013.  It also includes some tools for python.  And comes with the win10 SDK.

And no, MS does not provide any lite SDKs.

Comment: Thank you for sparing your valuable time, thats enlightening:)